# Pass Integer to another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer, int, viewcontroller

I'm trying to pass an Integer variable from one UIView to another. Basically, I have two UIView controllers set up. The first UIViewController has an integer called "page" and the seconds UIViewController has an Integer called "page_num".

What I am trying to do is to pass the variable from the Int "page" to the Int "page_num". But I get the following error:

> Property 'page_num' not found on object of type 'ImageViewer *'....

Here is my code (header file):

```
ImageViewer *seccondata;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ImageViewer *seconddata;
```

Here is my code (implementation file):

```
ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.seconddata = screen;
seconddata.page_num = page;
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What am I doing wrong? The code I have shown above worked when I wanted to pass a NSString from one UIViewController to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.page_num = page;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try this and no need to create any property.

Comment: I tried that but I still get the error "Property 'page_num' not found on object of type 'ImageViewer *' did you mean to access instance variable 'page_num'?

Comment: have you created page_num as a property in ImageViewer Class? if not then create it and synthesize it.

Comment: No I just declared it as an Integer in ImageViewer class. The reason for this is when I tried I got the following error: "Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type.

Comment: you have to create a property to use it in another class. It may help you.
it should be  
@property (assign) int page_num

Answer (score 0):

you should create the the object of the second class and access the variable with the help of that object..

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the second class objcet. and acess that varible using that objcet like **objcet.property**.

Like Below code

```
ImageViewer *screen = [[ImageViewer alloc] init];
screen.page_num = page;
```

Try this code..

Comment: I tried that but I still get the error "Property 'page_num' not found on object of type 'ImageViewer *' did you mean to access instance variable 'page_num'?

Comment: i think you have not creating the property of page_num and syntethise in .m and then try..